# Touch ID dialog showing two status bar

Tags: ios8, touch-id, iphone-64bit

When touch id is open from iphone 6 for inApp Purchases, it displaying the second status bar on the top of the screen and also if the video is playing on the current screen, it's stopped the video.

Don't know what's wrong the touch id.

Any help will be appreciate!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

This happens on applications that are not adapted to the resolution of iPhone 6 (plus). I already filed a bug with Apple and it was tagged as being a duplicate. We can hope it can be fixed.
In the meantime, adding the finer resolutions to iPhone 6 will solve the problem.